# Behavior of a conditional breakpoint in Python when using assignment

Tags: python

Recently I was debugging some code and inadvertently set a conditional breakpoint like the following:

```
my_var = some_val
```

When in reality I wanted

```
my_var == some_val
```

Obviously not something I want to do but it got me curious about that behavior when debugging (and other things that happen under the hood).  Is that statement executed and stored?  I.e. if the first line is used as the condition will `my_var` actually take on `some_val` every time that line is come across?

I noticed this because I always hit that breakpoint so the "condition" is always evaluating to `True`.

Was just wondering about what happens beneath that layer out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is evaluated but not stored. The reason is that because you can overwrite the `__eq__` method, `x == y` is a function call.

Short example :

```
class A:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print "Evaluated !"

a = A()
a == 1
# it prints "Evaluated !"
```